# How to deploy Xamarin forms app to device using Visual studio for mac

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin.forms

newbie to visual studio for mac.

I created a simple app using xamarin.forms and I wanted to deploy it to device (iOS and Android) for debugging purpose.

For iOS , I have deveoper acct and  for Android, I have enabled debugging in the phone.

When I plug android phone to MacBook via USB cable, I dont see any sign of Android phone name and this the same for iphone on Visual Studio for mac.

Can you help me or give a link to read how to deploy xamarin.forms app to device?

Please help.

Comment: Check this link [Set Up Device for Development](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/get-started/installation/set-up-device-for-development).

To debug iPhone you must chose Debug | iPhone option and you need a developer certificate, if you don't have just use an iPhone emulator from xCode.

Comment: Set the project you want to run/deploy as start up project. See [Xamarin Forum](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/104566/how-to-set-up-device-for-development)

Comment: For iOS you can cross check if the device is detecting by opening XCode and also make sure you set the target as "iPhone" and not "iPhoneSimulator"